# Get x newest files from directory

Tags: c#, .net, file

I want to implement function that receive `Directory` as parameter and `integer` that represent number of files and return the newest files from this `Direttory`

So i have this function:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt, int numberOfFiles)
    {
        try
        {
            var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory).SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return directories.Concat(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
```

Is it OK to use this `Linq`:

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\MyDirectory");
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).First();
```

1. Can i control number of returns file or it return only on ?
2. What happen if my folder contain only 2 files and i want the 3 newest files ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Take`:

```
var myFiles = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
              orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
              select f).Take(numberOfFiles);
```

or in method syntax:

```
myFiles = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).Take(numberOfFiles);
```

This will return as many files as there are (max. `numberOfFiles`). If you want three but there are only two you get two.

Comment: I try var myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(MyPath, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).Take(3); and 'string' does not contain a definition for 'LastWriteTime' and no extension method 'LastWriteTime' accepting a first argument

Comment: @user3599192: yes because you use the static `Directory.GetFiles` method instead of `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`. The former returns strings and the latter `FileInfo` objects. You have used a `DirectoryInfo` object yourself in your code above, why are you using `Directory.GetFiles` now?

Comment: is it Ok to use this: var item in Directory.GetFiles(MyPath, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(f => new FileInfo(f).CreationTime).Take(3))

Comment: @user3599192: yes, but it would be more efficient to use only what you need. You can use [`File.GetCreationTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes the path to the file: `var item in Directory.GetFiles(MyPath, "*.doc", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f)).Take(3))`

Answer (score 2):

> Can i control number of returns file or it return only on ?

Yes. Use [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> What happen if my folder contain only 2 files and i want the 3 newest
>   files ?

Use `.Take(3)`, It will only return the 2 files. There won't be an exception.

```
var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles()
             orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
             select f).Take(3);
```

Or with a method syntax:

```
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
                       .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                       .Take(3);
```